Server side rendering Next.js (App Router) with async component with the pathname
I am using Next.js 14 with the App Router, next-itnl and Sanity CMS to manage a multilingual website (English, French, and Vietnamese). I have a language switcher in the Navbar that fetches data based on the selected language using an asynchronous function and GROQ requests from Sanity. However, I've noticed a delay in the state update when switching languages.
When I click on a language, the data fetch is triggered, but the state update seems delayed, causing a noticeable "data delay" in displaying the new translated content.It shows the previous data when I click a language. I'm trying to use async function with the pathname

Navigation Bar :
import NavigationItems from '@/components/core/NavigationItems';
import NavigationLanguages from '@/components/core/NavigationLanguages';
import { getData} from '@/sanity/sanity-utils';
import { headers } from 'next/headers';

const NavigationBar = async () => {
  const headersList = headers();
  const fullUrl = headersList.get('referer') || '';

  const segments = fullUrl.split('/');
  const languages = ['en', 'fr', 'vn'];
  const language = segments.find(segment => languages.includes(segment));
  const data= await getData(language);

  return (
    <nav className='flex justify-between container py-4 items-center'>
      <div className='flex flex-row gap-8'>
        <NavigationItems items={data} />
        <NavigationLanguages />
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavigationBar;

Snippet of the language buttons
        <ul className='grid p-4 gap-2'>
          <a href='/en'>
            <li className='text-sm text-center  rounded-md px-4 py-2 transition-colors hover:bg-accent hover:text-accent-foreground focus:bg-accent focus:text-accent-foreground text-center'>
              English
            </li>
          </a>
          <a href='/fr'>
            <li className='text-sm text-center  rounded-md px-4 py-2 transition-colors hover:bg-accent hover:text-accent-foreground focus:bg-accent focus:text-accent-foreground text-center'>
              Français
            </li>
          </a>
          <a href='/vn'>
            <li className='text-sm text-center  rounded-md py-2 transition-colors hover:bg-accent hover:text-accent-foreground focus:bg-accent focus:text-accent-foreground text-center'>
              Tiếng Việt
            </li>
          </a>
        </ul>

Middleware.ts
import createIntlMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
 
export default async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const defaultLocale = request.headers.get('x-your-custom-locale') || 'fr';
 
  const handleI18nRouting = createIntlMiddleware({
    locales: ['en', 'fr', 'vn'],
    defaultLocale: 'fr'
  });
  const response = handleI18nRouting(request);
 
  response.headers.set('x-pathname', request.nextUrl.pathname);
 
  return response;
}
 
export const config = {
  // Match only internationalized pathnames
  matcher: ['/', '/(fr|en|vn)/:path*']
};

